# JSTL: core:redirect gives the error "Unknown tag"

Tags: redirect, jstl

I am taking my first steps with Spring and am doing a tutorial.

I am supposed to be redirecting to a page that displays some content using

> < core:redirect url="/portfolio.htm"/>

However that page never gets displayed. By navigating directly to the page I can see that it is there and it looks ok.

I get the error in Eclipse "Uknown tag (core:redirect)

I suspect this is giving me the problem, however I have imported the JSTL library and cannot see what I am doing wrong. The only thing I can think of is that core:... has been superseded by something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *install* and *declare* the taglib before you can use its tags.

1. Download [`jstl-1.2.jar`](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) and place it in `/WEB-INF/lib` or `/appserver/lib` if not done yet.
2. Declare [`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) in top of your JSP.
3. Now you can use [`<c:redirect />`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/redirect.html).

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the JSTL core taglib with the following statement at the top of your JSP?

```
<%@ taglib uri=" http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="core" %>
```

Most of the time it's done with `prefix="c"`, so referring to `core` wouldn't work.